# how to dynamically add / remove form while page refresh using php

Tags: php

How to dynamically add and remove input fields the form will stay while page refresh using [PHP](http://php.net/)?. could it possible to use session? please any [PHP](http://php.net/) script for this? thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```
<?php

$showEnterOther = "";
$showEnterOtherAsWell = "";

if(isset($_POST["show_form"])) {

    $showEnterOther = "<input type='text' name='whatever' />";
    $showEnterOtherAsWell = "<input type='text' name='whatever' />";

}

?>
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['username'])){echo $_POST['username'];} ?>"/>
<?php echo $showEnterOther; ?>
<?php echo $showEnterOtherAsWell; ?>
<input type="submit" name="show_form" value="Continue!" />
</form>
```